# onmouseover and onmouseout event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript
and I have simple code which worked fine in Google Chrome but the script didn't fire with Firefox.
It's just two events on `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` and changes images:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <script>

        function over() {
        image1.src = "13.JPG"
              }


        function out() {
        image1.src = "19.JPG"
              }
    </script>

    <style>
        img {
        height:200px; width:200px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <img  id="image1" onmouseover="over()" onmouseout="out()" />

</body>
</html>
```

It's worked fine in Google Chrome but not in Firefox and I want to know why?

Comment: You have to pass context as params to the functions.

Comment: u mean sth like that
  <script>
        function changeimg() {
            x = document.getElementById("image1")
            if (x.src = "13.JPG")
                x = "19.JPG"
            else {
                x.src = "13.JPG"
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="19.JPG" id="image1" onclick="changeimg()" />
</body>
but in general i want to know why this run without errors in google chroome

Comment: You could select the image element using `document.getElementById('image1')` and then set its source. In your case passing `this` and setting its `src` in function would work too - e.g. `over(this)`. You could also use css, `background-image` property and `:hover` pseudo class to change image - this should be pereferable way

Comment: thanks for your declaration , i know that css is a better way but this is just for learning purpose and in this example u have 2 images with one position so u can't declare 2 id's , so i make the code in this way and he work without error in chroome 
http://codepen.io/muhamedhashem/pen/vEgjJP
@dudelgrincen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how to do this with javascript:**

```js
function over() {
        document.getElementById('image1').src = "http://animalrescuetracy.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/playful-kitten-6683.jpg";
}


function out() {
        document.getElementById('image1').src  = "http://www.valleyvet.com/images/worming-your-kitten.png";
 }
```

```css
img {
        height:200px; width:200px;
        }
```

```html
<img  id="image1" src="" onmouseover="over()" onmouseout="out()"/>
```

**Here's how to do it with css:**

```css
#image1{
 content:url("http://www.valleyvet.com/images/worming-your-kitten.png");
    height:200px; width:200px;
  
}

#image1:hover{
 content:url("http://animalrescuetracy.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/playful-kitten-6683.jpg");
}
```

```html
 <img  id="image1" src=""/>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort and i think that my code should work too as your examples works fine in google chroome but didn]t work in firefox developer edition as mine too 
so can u check this pen for me http://codepen.io/muhamedhashem/pen/vEgjJP
and thanks again for your snippet @DelightedD0D

Comment: Apparently in firefox, your element must have the `src=""` property for it to appear on the screen. The property can be an empty string like `src=""` but is must be there. see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogBdGQ

Comment: Also when you use a tool like codepen, jsfiddle, or even the snippet feature here on SO, there are separate boxes for the html, css, and javascript. When you add your html, there's no need to add all the stuff above <body>or below </body> from your actual html file, that stuff will be added automatically by the tool.

Comment: yeah , src="" property fixes firefox and ie issue too , thanks